# ASP.NET MVC: moving from SQL Server Express to Azure

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, database, azure

I'm sure this has been asked before, but I'm not seeing anything in the similar questions. :(

I've got an ASP.NET MVC application I have developed locally that has been using a SQL Server Express database. In Azure, I recreated the database and taken the connection string it provided and updated the connection string in `web.config` of my app to use the new database.

When I publish the app to Azure, there doesn't appear to be any issues. However, when I hit a page in the app that accesses the db, it throws an error complaining it can't find the SQL Server Express database. Below is the main snippet from the error:

> SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server.
> The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 52 - Unable to locate a Local Database Runtime installation. Verify that SQL Server Express is properly installed and that the Local Database Runtime feature is enabled.)

So it seems like it's ignoring my connection string and still looking for a locally stored SQL Server Express database instead of using the Azure database I specify in the connection string. Any ideas why this might be? My guess is that I have missed something pretty basic (my usual guess when something that seems like it should be simple doesn't work. :) )

Connection strings per below request:

Local:

```
<add name="FCDbContext" connectionString="data source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;initial catalog=FormCenterResponder;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Azure Contection String:

```
<add name="FCDbContext" connectionString="Server=tcp:***azuredbserver here***,1433;Initial Catalog=***azuredb here***;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=***username here***;Password=***password here***;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

And configureservices per another request (it's pretty much defaults):

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection service)
{
   services.AddControllersWithViews();
}
```

Comment: **SHOW US** your connection strings - both for the local SQL Server Express, as well as the database in Azure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, mark this one up to being a asp.net/c# noob. I'll go ahead and post (the embarrassing) answer, though, in case others find themselves in my position.

A co-worker had a look at the code and found an excellent tutorial [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-model?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio). He was able to figure out what I had done wrong.

Basically, I had never registered the database context in Startup.ConfigureServices. I think this is why someone (who has since deleted their question) asked me to post that section of my code. Then that context can be read in by the controller files granting them the info they need to get access to the db.

App is now working as it should.